# Intellij 14 version python console file path link not working

Tags: intellij-idea, intellij-14, intellij-plugin

In Intellij 14, using Python plugin, I see a strange issue.
When I run my unit tests, I see few failures and in console it shows the file name with absolute path (as a hyperlink) and line number of stack trace. When I click on the hyperlink, control always moves to the 2nd line in the file. This behaviour is seen for every file link.

The same works fine in PyCharm. Looks like python plugin is broken with Intellij 14 version.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As far as I can tell there are only beta versions of the Python plugin available for IntelliJ 14. I've seen a bunch of minor issues and have been recommending to Python programmers in my company not to upgrade from 13 until a GA version of the plugin is available.

You can view the open issues here:

https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issues/PY